# Using Conditional If statements with JavaScript DOM Table?

Tags: javascript, html

I have been given a table that has been created using the DOM and now I have to use if statements to print specific areas of that table. For example in the second photo, when i click **1 - 2 million**, it should show the table but only display the countries that have a population that's between 1 and 2 million. My teacher has barely taught us JavaScript deeply and now gives us a DOM assignment that uses JavaScript If Statements. I would appreciate if someone could give an explanation on how i can print specific parts of the table when i click the links/button above. Thanks!

[image: Given Table]]

[image: Identifying the Task]

Comment: You can add a class (ex : millions) to row which have population >1millions and play with visibility; or with a loop on rows set visibility with condition

Comment: My prof didn't even teach us classes lol

Comment: So take second options : do a loop on the rows and set visibility on condition; I won't give you the code (it's simple, you can do it); if you need some info https://www.w3schools.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a roadmap:

- Loop through your submenus with a [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/for) (or [`for ... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/for...in)) statement and attach a click event listener on each one with [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- In the callback, [`this`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp) will refer to the `<li>` (or `<a>`, or whatever) element you clicked (and which is linked to an event). So you can access the DOM clicked element's data nor attributes.
- In function of the clicked submenu, filter your `<table>` the way you want thanks to `if` statements. (even better: [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/switch) statement) Visually, rows will be hidden. In Javascript, you will update [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) attribute of the element.

Below an example. I propose to you to try to do it yourself with elements I gave you. Open the snippet if you are really lost.

**Exemple:**

> Other functions/methods/statements I used below: [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset), [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Op%C3%A9rateurs/instanceof), [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/parseInt), [`onload`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp), [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children)

```js
// Always interact with the DOM when it is fully loaded.
window.onload = () => {
  // Gets all <button> with a "data-filter-case" attribute.
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-filter-case]');
  
  // For each <button>, attach a click event listener.
  for (let i in buttons) {
    const button = buttons[i];
    
    // The last item of "buttons" is its length (number), so we have to check if
    // it is a HTMLElement object.
    if (button instanceof HTMLElement) {
      button.addEventListener('click', filterTable); // Will execute the "filterTable" function on click.
    }
  }
}

// The function which will filter the table.
function filterTable(e) {
  // Useless in my exemple, but if you have <a> instead of <button>,
  // it will not execute its original behavior.
  e.preventDefault();
  
  // Get the value of "data-filter-case" attribute.
  const filterCase = this.dataset.filterCase;
  // Get all table body rows.
  const tableRows = document.querySelectorAll('table > tbody > tr');
  
  // Update display style of each row in function of the case.
  for (let i in tableRows) {
    const row = tableRows[i];
    
    if (row instanceof HTMLElement) {
      if (filterCase === 'more-than-44') {
        if (parseInt(row.children[1].innerText) <= 44) {
          // Hide the row.
          row.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
          // Reset display style value.
          row.style.display = '';
        }
      } else if (filterCase === 'less-than-27') {
        if (parseInt(row.children[1].innerText) >= 27) {
          row.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
          row.style.display = '';
        }
      } else if (filterCase === 'reset') {
        row.style.display = '';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" data-filter-case="more-than-44">More than 44</button>
<button type="button" data-filter-case="less-than-27">Less than 27</button>
<button type="button" data-filter-case="reset">Show all</button>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>45</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td>24</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Would this be handled differently if my table was created using pure DOM?

Comment: What can i replace HTMLElement by since my table in made using the DOM?

Comment: @MichaelJoe Do not wonder about that, [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) is a tree representation of your HTML document.

Comment: My table with around 120 rows is inside a function called generateTable(). Won't that function have to be used somewhere in the code to display specific parts of the table?

Comment: @MichaelJoe - Generate all your rows before making the filters.